# Splunk Streamlined search for specific fields only

Tags: field, splunk, splunk-query, spl

I've ran out of GoogleFu, so if anyone can point me in the right direction or a better term or two to Google...  I'm trying to figure out Splunk SPL syntax to search 4 different fields for the same value, any match in the four fields wins, with out searching every field for the `TERM(<IP>)`.

```
index="main" packets_out>0 action="allowed" TERM(192.168.2.1) 
| fields src_ip, dest_ip, dest_translated_ip, src_translated_ip,packets_out 
| head 10
```

These will always be constant: `index="main" packets_out>0 action="allowed"`

The IP will be the only variable that will change and I'm trying to make it as simple as possible for others to "open search, change 1 IP, click go".

This works as is, but once I try to search against prod with 2000 devices.. I'm expecting my query time will not be 1 second anymore, even with using "Fast Mode" search.  I've reduced the 4 second query time to 1. Along with the size of data queried with this already, in my home lab, but I don't think this is going to scale very well.

Is there a better way to do this, besides plugging in 10-20 device names into the query like this?  I would rather not have static device names, so if someone "forgets" to update the query; I'll get blamed for the external IP overlap issue.

```
index="main" packets_out>0 action="allowed" TERM(192.168.2.1) dvc_name="firewall1" OR dvc_name="firewall2" <*18>
| fields src_ip, dest_ip, dest_translated_ip, src_translated_ip,packets_out 
| head 10
```

Raw log if needed:

```
Apr  7 23:59:55 192.168.2.1 Apr  7 23:59:55 wall 1,2021/04/07 23:59:54,012801092758,TRAFFIC,end,2560,2021/04/07 23:59:54,192.168.2.189,173.194.219.94,10.10.10.2,173.194.219.94,web_access_out-1,,,quic,vsys1,trust,untrust,ethernet1/8,ethernet1/2,splunk,2021/04/07 23:59:54,2004,1,53384,443,59427,443,0x400050,udp,allow,5528,2350,3178,15,2021/04/07 23:57:53,1,any,0,5261883,0x0,192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255,United States,0,6,9,aged-out,0,0,0,0,,wall,from-policy,,,0,,0,,N/A,0,0,0,0,f863e426-7e87-4999-b5cb-bc6dc38d788f,0,0,,,,,,,,0.0.0.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2021-04-07T23:59:55.282-04:00,,
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use `OR`:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp (fieldA="myval" OR fieldB="myval" OR fieldC="myval")
```

Parenthesis added for clarity/readability